# Lazy Loading not working, not displaying image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-lazyload

I am trying to use a fade in lazy loading effect. Although I have followed all the instructions but still the image is not appearing! Can anybody help more? code:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="collateral-body-image">
    <img class="lazy" data-original="images/vivid-collateral.jpg" width="1920" height="594">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect: "fadeIn"
  });
});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: did you verify the jquery and lazyload links? it might be a simple wrong url issue...

Comment: how do i verify them?

Comment: either open dev console of your browser and go to sources and see if the files load correctly, or copy&paste the url to your address bar and append them to the current path (eg: if your site is located on **www.mysite.com/myproject/example.html**, then your links as you posted in your snippet are supposed to be located at **www.mysite.com/myproject/jquery.js** and same for lazyload). and see if the files open in your browser.

Comment: Ok I've checked via the console and it says file not found? I don't understand...how do i make sure its installed then?

Comment: you dont need to install them. just download the plugins (search on google where from there are plenty of places) and put them in a folder in your site. if you use IDE like visual studio, you can just drag the file into the page from the solution explorer and it will create a link with a proper url for you. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/s9pkjus3/) is a working example fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna get it running just load it using CDN urls.
Later you can download this scripts on your local and serve it using a local webserver on localhost.

Quick to-run code,

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="collateral-body-image">
        <img class="lazy" data-original="http://montanasteele.com/wp-content/uploads/gallery/vivid-condos/vivid-collateral-02.jpg" width="800" height="800">
    </div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("img.lazy").lazyload( {
           effect: "fadeIn"
        } );
    } );
</script>
```